# Missing something in Async typescript d3

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

The following is the code that I am trying to load:

```
let train;
async f()=>{d3.csv("training.csv", function(data){train = data;});}
    console.log(train);
```

I am getting the following error:

> TypeScript error: Error TS2468: Cannot find global value 'Promise'.

I am could not understand why this error is occurring. I guess I am missing something but could not understand what it is.

I have tried: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2861#issuecomment-231564641

Comment: The line `async ()=>{d3.csv("training.csv", function(data){train = data;});}` makes no sense whatsoever. It defines a function expression that is immediately discarded. What were you trying to do here?

Comment: @Bergi Sorry but I didn't understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5683) suggests the following solution:

```
try adding "lib": ["es2018", "dom"], to tsconfig.json in compilerOptions section

tsconfig.json file:

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
        ...
```